# do not do download apk in enterprise mode of WSO2 IOT and EMM

Tags: android, wso2, iot

I am implementing an IOT WSO2 and we are not able to download
Of the apks that we put in it, already in public mode at the time of downloading, redirects
For Google play and we were able to download it.
Has anyone caught this problem yet? Is this a WSO2 IOT Bug? Do you have any patches for correction?

Answer (score 0):

If you push a public app that is how it is working. Once you install a public Android app, the Google Play Store will be popped up with the app details screen in the device.

If you push an enterprise application it will be downloaded to the device and popped up. but user has to manually install the application.

If you want to install the application silently you need to make the agent app device owner or use the system app. If you use the system app it should be singed by the key that you use to sign the firmware.